# Storing structs inside a vector with insert function c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, insert

I'm currently trying to write a program that is supposed to store incoming data from cin to a vector with elements of a struct-type.

```
struct data{

  int times;
  string name;
};
```

and storing them in the vector

```
vector<data> data_list;
```

the problem I have is the syntax for storing them in the vector using the insert function.

I've tried with `data_list.insert(data_list.begin(),5);`

for storing the int value 5 at the first index but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you *expect* this to work? `5` is not a `data`. It’s unclear what your goal is.

Answer (score 4):

Since your vector holds `data` elements, you need to pass a `data` object into the `insert()` function, e.g.:

```
data d = {5, "string_value"};
data_list.insert( data_list.begin(), d );
```

Answer (score 3):

By declaring

```
vector<data> data_list;
//     ^^^^
```

you explicitly say that `data_list` will store `data` object.

You are trying to store `int` inside a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) containing `data` object. You need pass a data object to the `insert` function:

```
data obj = {5, "name"};             // Declare the data object
                                    // data.times = 5
                                    // data.name  = "name"
data_list.insert( data_list.begin(), obj ); // Insert it
//                                   ^^^
```

Comment: @user2787397 Are you declaring your `struct` inside a header file (.h) ? And is this header included in the source file where you have this code ?

Comment: It's defined as struct data{...}; inside the source file before the main function.

Comment: @user2787397 Take a look at [**this example**](http://ideone.com/UtXFS4), this works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical/correct way to do that is to define `std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, data& d)`, then initialize or assign your vector using input iterators. That means, do not use insert, use vector::assign for the whole sequence, using input iterators (or vector::push_back).